# jquery add and remove the unbind

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i'm doing u.i using jquery. The thing is, I created a **container** that has a **button** of **add** and **remove** inside.

If I click the `add` it will append to another div only once and then.

if i click the `remove` on the appended div it will remove and it can be added to another div again as if the event handler was removed.

I've tried the .unbind but it doesn't work on my code.

Please help me here with my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/8mNKN/

```
$(".more").one("click",function(e) {

        $(this).parent().clone().appendTo("#we");

    });

    $(document).on("click","#we .remove",function() {
        $('.more').unbind('click.MyNamespace');
        $(this).parent(".container").remove();
    });

<div class="container">
    <p>There are 0 boxes</p>

    <a href="#" class="more">Add more +</a>
    <a href="#" class="remove">Add more +</a>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
    <p>There are 0 boxes</p>

    <a href="#" class="more">Add more +</a>
    <a href="#" class="remove">Remove -</a>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
    <p>There are 0 boxes</p>

    <a href="#" class="more">Add more +</a>
    <a href="#" class="remove">Remove -</a>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="we">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly then

```
$(".more").on("click",function(e) {
    var ct = $(this).closest(".container");
    if(ct.data('cloned')){
        return;
    }
    ct.clone().appendTo("#we").data('source', ct);
    ct.data('cloned', true);
});

$(document).on("click","#we .remove",function() {
    var ct = $(this).closest(".container");
    ct.data('source').data('cloned', false)
    ct.remove();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sMQS2/)

Comment: wow, it's work perfectly, thanks arun, i will not be terminated anymore, thanks so much :) more power to you